# Retrieve variable from Java code and assign to TestNG as parameter

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, testng, appium

How can I get the required variable from my Java class and assign it as a parameter in my `testng.xml`?
For example, this is the variable I want to get:

```
String chatTitle = driver.findElement (By.id ("title")).getText ();
```

I want to assign it as a parameter to my test suite:

```
<parameter name="chat-title" value="chatTitle variable value" />
```

Any advice?

Comment: you need to provide some dynamic xml generation mechanism. For example take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834457/dynamic-testng-xml-creation-getting-wrong-xml-where-i-am-wrong)

Comment: Is it not useful for you to use a data-provider for this?